# Null data in hashmap kotlin

Tags: android, kotlin, hashmap

I want to insert data into a `HashMap`. key is an `Integer` and value is a `String`. Value is received from external source.

I'm putting the received key and value into the `Hashmap` but when I try to print the value I'm getting `null`.

Why is this happening?

```
private var hashMap: HashMap<Int, String>? = null

    fun addData(key : Int, value : String) {
        hashMap?.put(key, value)

        println("********Maaaaapphasshh = $hashMap")  //null why?

        hashMap?.forEach { (key, value ) ->
            println("********$key = $value ")       //null why?
        }
    }
```

Comment: hashMap: HashMap<Int, String>? = null --> You create the hashmap as null and never instantiate it.. Try to replace by hashMap: HashMap<String, Int>? = HashMap<String, Int> ()

Comment: Oh god, i'm so estupid. Thx

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`hashMap` is being created as `null` and it was never instantiated:

```
private var hashMap: HashMap<Int, String>? = null
```

Try to replace by:

```
private var hashMap: HashMap<Int, String>? = HashMap<Int, String> ()
```

Comment: And only use `var` if you actually need to reassign it.